# Highcharts stacked column how to use different label on each category

Tags: highcharts

Hi guys I want to achieve something like this using HighCharts Stacked Column

[image]

This is my current code

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    }
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Cukai Semasa', 'Tunggakan Cukai']
},
series: [{
    name: 'Baki Cukai Semasa',
    data: [69000000, 60000000]
}, {
    name: 'Kutipan Semasa',
    data: [69000000, 60000000]
}]
```

Which resulting this chart

[image]

As you can see, my generated chart dont have the label for Tunggakan Cukai category (Baki Kutipan Tunggakan and Kutipan Tunggakan).

How to achieve this using Stacked Column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this and showing all points in legend is by making them individual series:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Baki Cukai Semasa',
  data: [69000000, null]
}, {
  name: 'Kutipan Semasa',
  data: [60000000, null]
}, {
  name: 'Baki Kutipan Tunggakan',
  data: [null, 69000000]
}, {
  name: 'Kutipan Tunggakan',
  data: [null, 60000000]
}]
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/05a9ctep/) of it in use.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `series.legendType: 'point'`.

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      legendType: 'point',
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Cukai Semasa', 'Tunggakan Cukai']
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      name: 'Baki Cukai Semasa',
      y: 69000000,
      color: '#72AD4D'
    }, {
      name: 'Baki Kutipan Tunggakan',
      y: 60000000,
      color: '#FC3D45'
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      name: 'Kutipan Semasa',
      y: 69000000,
      color: '#AAD092'
    }, {
      name: 'Kutipan Tunggakan',
      y: 60000000,
      color: '#FD7C82'
    }]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9xmnrqp2/